# SQL query to count number of Thursdays worked in last 10 weeks

Tags: sql, oracle

**Oracle 11g**

I need to come up with a query that should return the employees who worked at least 3 Thursdays in the last 10 Thursdays from a give date.

As an example If were to run the query today (Jun18-2015) It should look for last 10 Thursdays and return employee id if the employee worked on at least 3 Thursdays.

```
    EmployeeID    Date           Clock In Time      Clock Out Time
    EMPLOYE A    14-may-2015      8am                4pm
    EMPLOYE A    15-may-2015      8am                4pm
    EMPLOYE A    16-may-2015      8am                4pm
    EMPLOYE A    17-may-2015      8am                4pm
    EMPLOYE A    1-jun-2015       8am                4pm
    EMPLOYE A    2-jun-2015       8am                4pm
    EMPLOYE A    4-jun-2015       8am                4pm
    EMPLOYE A    11-jun-2015      8am                4pm
    EMPLOYE A    12-jun-2015      8am                4pm
    EMPLOYE A    14-jun-2015      8am                4pm
    EMPLOYE A    15-jun-2015      8am                4pm
    EMPLOYE A    16-jun-2015      8am                4pm
    EMPLOYE A    17-jun-2015      8am                4pm

    EMPLOYEE B   16-may-2015      8am                4pm
    EMPLOYEE B   17-may-2015      8am                4pm
    EMPLOYEE B   1-jun-2015       8am                4pm
    EMPLOYEE B   2-jun-2015       8am                4pm
    EMPLOYEE B   4-jun-2015       8am                4pm
    EMPLOYEE B   5-jun-2015       8am                4pm
    EMPLOYEE B   6-jun-2015       8am                4pm
    EMPLOYEE B   7-jun-2015       8am                4pm
    EMPLOYEE B   8-jun-2015       8am                4pm
    EMPLOYEE B   10-jun-2015      8am                4pm
    EMPLOYEE B   11-jun-2015      8am                4pm
```

- In the above dataset, employee A worked on three Thursdays (14/4/11)
  Valid employee.
- Employee B worked only two Thursdays (4 and 11) - Invalid employee : should not be returned 

   I tried using NEXT_DAY function in Oracle but couldn't really come up with the logic. More importantly, I don't want to clutter my sql with unnessary joins making it more complex than it needs to be.

Comment: please show your attempt.

Comment: if my answer could solve your problem, please put a green tick to close the thread

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select EmployeeID
from T
where Date > sysdate() - 70 days and to_char(Date, 'd') = '4'
group by EmployeeID
having count(*) >= 3
```

I assume you don't want to exclude current date so you will want to use strictly greater than (rather than greater than or equal) so you don't accidentally count too many days in the case when current date falls on Thursday. I'll just assume that this approach from another answer is the proper way to get day of week but you definitely always need to be careful about the settings for you locale/region. Also there's no reason for an inline view because you can accomplish the same result easily with `having`.

Answer (score 1):

Below query give you day of the date

```
select to_char(to_date('23.06.2008', 'dd.mm.yyyy'), 'Day') from dual
```

add its select expression to your queries select clause and name it as Day Column. then use it in the where clause like where Day = 'Thursdays'

Comment: You haven't addressed the part of the problem relating to 3 out of 10 most recent Thursdays.

Answer (score 1):

In Oracle, you can use

`select count(*) from tablename where to_char(date, 'd') = *X*`

Where x is a number for thursday based on day of the week 1-7 (probably 4 or 5). Depending on your region your week may start on a different day so be sure to verify.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `to_char(date,'DAY')` function to get the name of the date. This is better than getting the number of the day, because depending on your nls settings, the days may be numbered differently.

```
Select employeeID, count(*) as 'THURSDAYS_WORKED'
    where date >= trunc(sysdate) - 70 --get last 10 weeks
    and UPPER(to_char(date, 'DAY')) == 'THURSDAY' --get all thursdays
    group by employeeID
    having count(*) >= 3 --get only those employees who worked 3 or more thursdays
```